# How to stop a infinite running process(ztail) started by a ssh session after that session is closed

Tags: linux, linux-networking, linux-kernel

I have a peculiar problem. My server supports multiple ssh session simultaneously, so that multiple admins can manage it simultaneously.

We have a command which calls `ztail` to show the compressed log files and when the current ssh session is closed (without pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, to stop the `tail` command), the command should ideally stop working.

But what I observed when I start a new ssh session is that the process `ztail` is still running in the background and consuming CPU, even though the previous session was closed.

How can I determine when the session is closed, so that I can use that variable/flag to close/stop any commands initiated by that previously closed session?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what is the command that you run in your `ssh` session and in turn invokes ztail, nor whether this command keeps running or not.

When you close the session, that command receives a `SIGHUP` signal, and should then dispose of `ztail`.